# Тяжелый запрос в MySQL тормозит все остальные

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица (MyISAM) на 1,500,000 записей, раз в несколько часов по крону запускается скрипт и делает очень тяжелый запрос в нее (только чтение)

Проблема в том что при этом начинают жутко тормозить все остальные запросы и соответственно всеь сайт. Простая выборка по id, которая занимала 0.001 сек, занимает 3-5 сек :(

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы пусть тяжелый запрос выполнялся медленнее, но при этом все остальные работали нормально?

Все это на выделенном сервере с 2 xeonами и 16 gb памяти...

Вот текущий my.cnf:

```
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size = 32M
thread_concurrency = 8
```

Comment: Напишите сюда запрос, вместе подумаем как его оптимизировать..

Comment: Сам запрос бы увидеть

Comment: аналогов bulk collect+limit в Mysql нету?

Answer (score 2):

помоему, select запрос не делает lock.

Но как вариант сделать експлейн и оптимизировать немного запрос, добавить пару индексов ...

Answer (score 1):

Можно также разделить данные на 2 таблицы.. data и data_history.
Тяжело пытаться угадать что там у вас, без нормального объяснения.. (

Answer (score 0):

Может, есть вариант не читать каждый раз таблицу, а "инкрементально" изменять данные через триггеры, навешенные на изменения в большой таблице? Т.е. если в простейшем случае ваш запрос это `COUNT(*)`, то хранить это число в отдельной таблице и корректировать его.